# copying a file to a different folder

Tags: c#

I have a file in a folder, every time a user makes a change to that one file i want to back it up in a different folder with a different name each time.

This is what i have so far, just not sure how to change the name of
the back up file to be like backup1.txt, backup2.txt and so on

```
try
{
    System.IO.File.Copy(ppFileName,MoveFilesForBackUp);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to modify the destination filename `MoveFilesForBackUp` to use some sort of sequential numbering.

So first of all you need to write a function that can generate for you sequential backup numbers.

Then each time you want to perform a backup you'll need to find out what the next sequential filename should be. Then you try to copy the file to the new name, and if that fails with an `IOException` specifying that the file already exists, you move on to the next sequential name, etc., until this works.

Naively, one would think that finding the next sequential name should guarantee the `Copy` to work, but in between the search and the actual call to Copy, the user or some other program could have created a file with that name (a race condition), so to be robust, you'll need be able to handle the error and try other names.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
string path = @"F:\\EE";

var nextFileName = "backup"
                   + (Convert.ToInt32(Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.txt")
                   .Select(p => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(p)
                   .Replace("backup", "")).Last())
                   + 1)
                   .ToString()
                   + ".txt";
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks
i just added this line of code that when its copied its renamed to the date and time it was copied.

```
System.IO.File.Copy(ppFileName, Properties.Settings.Default.MoveFilesForBackUp + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HHmmtt")+".pptx");
```